# Cannot install librosa python, how can I uninstall llvmlite?

Tags: python, librosa

I have recently tried to install `librosa` on Windows using `pip install librosa`. Nevertheless, this error appears:

> Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and
>   thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

As a solution, I have executed `conda update --all`, and `conda install numba=0.39.0`, without any improvement.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just have to type the command you want to execute with the `--user` tag. 
In your case, it would be:

```
pip install librosa --user
```

Comment: This worked (got through install), however when I try to import the installed library, it does not show up..

Answer (score 9):

Let me try to help.

I recently faced that problem and get rid from it by using following command.

```
--ignore-installed
```

Comment: But how do I use it? I've tried `pip install librosa --ignore-installed` but I get the same error

Comment: pip install --ignore-installed librosa

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
pip install librosa --ignore-installed llvmlite
```