# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyts'

Tags: python, pandas, installation, prompt

When i try to install in anaconda prompt:

```
pip install pyts
```

It gives to me this error: `ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

How can i solve it?

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766671/cannot-install-librosa-python-how-can-i-uninstall-llvmlite

Comment: WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in '...' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Now i have this warning, how can i add the directory to PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go in and check your PATH with python, there are tons of great YT videos on working with environmental variables and utilizing PATH on Windows.

Then when installing pyts:

```
pip install pyts --user
```

It sounds like you are having issues with PATH not correctly configured first and foremost.